# Trying to loop over mysql json field using prisma and typescript

Tags: mysql, reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I have a json field in mysql, and I am trying to loop over it.

I found that I should do this according to the Prisma docs:

```
  const Booking = await prisma.Booking.findUnique({
    where: { id: parseInt(params.id) },
  });

  let cateringObject: CateringItem[] | null = null;

  if (
    Booking?.catering &&
    typeof Booking?.catering === "object" &&
    Array.isArray(Booking?.catering)
  ) {
    const cateringObject = Booking?.catering as Prisma.JsonArray;
  }
```

I did try create this interface

```
interface CateringItem {
  quantity: number;
  productName: string;
  productPrice: number;
}
```

The error is when I try to loop over

```
          <ul>
            {cateringObject &&
              cateringObject.map((item) => <li>{item.productName}</li>)}
          </ul>
```

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 let cateringObject: CateringItem[] | null = null;
//
//
//
const cateringObject = Booking?.catering as Prisma.JsonArray;
```

Usually you cannot redeclare as a constant if you wish to use `cateringObject` outside the block. This might be what's triggering the error as Typescript cannot infer the type of `cateringObject`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I left `let` and removed `const` so it is just `cateringObject = Booking...` but now I get another error: `Type 'JsonArray' is not assignable to type 'CateringItem[]`

Comment: This is common if typescript cannot ensure ``JsonArray`` is an actual array of ``CateringItems``. You would want to use a ``Type Guard`` here, or write better assertions, but that is outside the context of the question, and should be an easy fix as I see you already have a clue how to do type assertions judging from the code, just minor fixing since ``Booking.catering`` could be ``unknown``. If not just do Type guard functions as they are safer approach and check at runtime.